# summing dummy variables returns 0.0

Tags: python, pandas

I have code below where I'm creating dummy variables for the property_type field and year_built field.  I then concat those dataframes together with my original dataframe.  Next I drop the records where lender is NaN.  Then finally I'm trying to sum the dummy variable columns I created for property_type and group by lender.  However I seem to be getting all 0 when I sum which is incorrect.  Is there something I'm doing wrong when I sum or create the dummy variables?  I've included sample data below.

```
Code:

propType_dummies=pd.get_dummies(data_16['property_type'])
yearBuilt_dummies=pd.get_dummies(data_16['year_built'])

data_dummies=pd.concat([data_16,propType_dummies,yearBuilt_dummies],axis=1)

# dropping records where lender is NaN
NoLenderMissing=data_dummies[pd.notnull(data_dummies['lender'])]

sum_propType=NoLenderMissing.groupby('lender')[list(propType_dummies)].sum()

print(sum_propType.describe())

Out Put:

          RAPT     RCON     RCOO     RDUP     RMFD     RMOB     RMSC     RQUA  \
count  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0   
mean       0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   
std        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   
min        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   
25%        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   
50%        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   
75%        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   
max        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0   

          RSFR     RTIM     RTRI     VRES  
count  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0  26142.0  
mean       0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  
std        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  
min        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  
25%        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  
50%        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  
75%        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  
max        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0  


Data:
              id                                   property_address  \
695169  562691875                    2652 LOBELIA RD ALPINE CA 91901   
695252  562884083                                                NaN   
695285  563031163                  505 MISSOURI ST MARTINEZ CA 94553   
695314  563191018                                                NaN   
695320  563229683                 123 ARLENE TER SAN RAFAEL CA 94903   
695324  563261078                                                NaN   
695326  563261259                                                NaN   
695328  563273320               433 PINE RIDGE DR SAN RAMON CA 94582   
695335  563275275                                                NaN   
695336  563275426                2146 W 75TH ST LOS ANGELES CA 90047   
695342  563354643       4040 HARLINGTON CIR EL DORADO HILLS CA 95762   
695345  563355362                                                NaN   
695346  563355442         14817 SHERMAN WAY 11 VAN NUYS CA 914052260   
695349  563356931                     33085 FOX RD TEMECULA CA 92592   
695350  563357396                                                NaN   
695351  563357951              141 MONTICELLO AVE RIO LINDA CA 95673   
695352  563358223                 241 SHRIKE CIR SACRAMENTO CA 95834   
695353  563358700               7098 SITIO CORAZON CARLSBAD CA 92009   
695355  563359313                                                NaN   
695357  563359925                1095 MICRO PL SAN JOSE CA 951203359   
695359  563422004               101 CASCADES CIR UNION CITY CA 94587   
695360  563422381              907 CHEYENNE DR WALNUT CREEK CA 94598   
695361  563422415                  3562 WAXWING WAY ANTIOCH CA 94509   
695362  563422689                   3022 MILLS DR BRENTWOOD CA 94513   
695364  563429038              5225 PLA VADA DR BAKERSFIELD CA 93306   
695365  563429201             8427 ZEILER AVE PANORAMA CITY CA 91402   
695366  563429441  3437 SAN GABRIEL RIVER PKWY BALDWIN PARK CA 91706   
695367  563429494         18029 RIVER CIR #3 CANYON COUNTRY CA 91387   
695371  563430973               4695 MARLENE DR SANTA MARIA CA 93455   
695375  563446919             1007 HOWARD AVE #20 ESCONDIDO CA 92029   
695379  563492900           1428 PECAN GROVE DR DIAMOND BAR CA 91765   
695380  563492901           1428 PECAN GROVE DR DIAMOND BAR CA 91765   
695386  563503033                                                NaN   
695391  563570048                 7930 SEDAN ST CANOGA PARK CA 91304   
695393  563571900            3439 ZORINA WAY SACRAMENTO CA 958264650   
695396  563580926             3449 W MENDOCINO AVE STOCKTON CA 95204   
695400  563633816              1869 MCFARLANE ST SAN MARINO CA 91108   
695401  563634908              2134 REDCLIFF ST LOS ANGELES CA 90039   
695404  563636047                     9 GREENLEAF #7 IRVINE CA 92604   
695414  563648161                                                NaN   
695415  563698267             4850 EMBASSY CIR #13 LA PALMA CA 90623   
695416  563706968                   308 FAIRWAY DR PACIFICA CA 94044   
695417  563707304              1768 CARSWELL CT SUISUN CITY CA 94585   
695419  563718676                 9502 ALBERT DR DUBLIN CA 945684237   
695420  563719154              190 CORTSEN RD PLEASANT HILL CA 94523   
695421  563719342                                                NaN   
695422  563720222          111 S DE LACEY AVE #110 PASADENA CA 91105   
695423  563721975                       82058 DUNN DR INDIO CA 92203   
695424  563722042         6738 HARWOOD CIR #35 PALM SPRINGS CA 92264   
695425  563722207                  2725 MANZANITA WAY HEMET CA 92545   

                                           buyer                      seller  \
695169                  THOMAS,KELLY L & ROBYN D               HAYES,ROBYN D   
695252                          GONZALEZ ENT INC             GONZALEZ,HERMAN   
695285                      SPATZ,ELAINE M TRUST              SPATZ,ELAINE M   
695314              HAMMOND,CHARLES & DEBI TRUST  DABBAGH 2011 GRANTOR TRUST   
695320                           LEVITAN,KORIE E               LEVITAN,HENRY   
695324                MARTIN,MARCIA J 1997 TRUST             MARTIN,MARCIA J   
695326                       STEPHENSON,REGINALD         MEYER,PAIGE & MOLLY   
695328                  PURDY,SANDY LIVING TRUST                 PURDY,SANDY   
695335                         KODA,RYAN & SAGHI                  KODA,SAGHI   
695336                ALBERT,ELNORA LIVING TRUST                         NaN   
695342  MEHRANPOUR,MEHRDAD|MASSOUD-ANSARI,SONBOL                         NaN   
695345                                 HMBAP LLC                         NaN   
695346                            CASTILLO,SUSAN                         NaN   
695349                              PAPICH,KEN V                         NaN   
695350                          DENKERS,ROBERT K              BARAJAS,CRUZ H   
695351                RIVERA,GERARDO & ELIZABETH              RIVERA,GERARDO   
695352                   SINGH,MANJOT|KAUR,IKMAN                         NaN   
695353                                PARK,KISOO                  KIM,HYUNJA   
695355                   LARA,AURELIO & EDUWIGES                LARA,AURELIO   
695357              SINGH,INDRAJIT K & MADHULIKA                 SINGH TRUST   
695359             DHILLON,KULDEEP S & AMANDIP K                         NaN   
695360                        CHANG FAMILY TRUST                         NaN   
695361                    ZEIDAN,BASHAR & DENISE                         NaN   
695362                      SCHENONE,CATHERINE C                         NaN   
695364                               SHINN,KELLY       THRASHER LIVING TRUST   
695365                  PHAM,THYPHAM & KIMOANH T                PHAM,THYPHAM   
695366             MONTES,SILVINO JR & JAQUELINE                         NaN   
695367                         KIM,TAE & DIANE D                     KIM,TAE   
695371                         ADAMS,ROBERT A JR               ADAMS,HELEN L   
695375        MEDRANO ALEJANDRA L P|PEREZ,JAVIER            PARHIZKARI,BRIAN   
695379                            CHAO,HSIU-SHAN    BRIDGETTE INVESTMENT LLC   
695380                            CHAO,HSIU-SHAN                  YU,KUO-PIN   
695386                 RIZZO FAMILY LIVING TRUST     CRAWFORD J A 2003 TRUST   
695391                                SEE,LOIS R               SEE,WILLIAM L   
695393                 MEUSBURGER,JOSEPH & DEBRA                         NaN   
695396                 FLENNER,PAUL & VICTORIA A                         NaN   
695400             TAYBACK,CHRISTOPHER & CLARE P                         NaN   
695401                               DAMCO TRUST           MCNICHOLAS,DENNIS   
695404      YATO,CHRISTOPHER M|SANCHEZ,GISELDA P                         NaN   
695414                ROCHA,GUSTAVO & ANGELICA M               GOMEZ,ALBEIRO   
695415              FUJII,TETSU T|KANAMOTO,KELLY                         NaN   
695416          BUHAGIAR,GREGORY M & KATHERINE B                         NaN   
695417                ERVIN,CHEVELL L & TAMELA M        HAINES,SHON & LISA M   
695419                    KUANG,XIAORONG|LU,MING              KUANG,XIAORONG   
695420              BALDWIN,G F & B L 2005 TRUST      BALDWIN B L 2005 TRUST   
695421                          BEACH,LAWRENCE I               BEACH,DONNA J   
695422                         TSAI FAMILY TRUST                         NaN   
695423                          BOESIGER,JAMES A       GARCIA-BOESIGER,JENNA   
695424                 FUNK,DAVID|BRITTON,SHEILA                         NaN   
695425                   MERCER,GARY W & KATHY L         HAUSER FAMILY TRUST   

       transaction_date  property_id property_type  transaction_amount  \
695169       2016-01-04     26054756          RSFR                   0   
695252       2016-01-05     25209945          RSFR                   0   
695285       2016-01-06     28471027          RSFR                   0   
695314       2016-01-05     28615172          RMSC              145000   
695320       2016-01-04     29945401          RCON                   0   
695324       2016-01-07     24979978          VRES                   0   
695326       2016-01-04     24371952          RCON              148000   
695328       2016-01-04    113547296          RCON                   0   
695335       2016-01-04     30719839          RSFR                   0   
695336       2016-01-07     32022518          RSFR                   0   
695342       2016-01-05     28656587          RSFR                   0   
695345       2016-01-08     31513160          VRES                   0   
695346       2016-01-06     30740556          RCON                   0   
695349       2016-01-02     81983739          RSFR                   0   
695350       2016-01-05     27729327          RSFR              120000   
695351       2016-01-04     39595918          RSFR                   0   
695352       2016-01-04    104958371          RSFR                   0   
695353       2016-01-05    122795468          RSFR                   0   
695355       2016-01-12     23889066          RDUP                   0   
695357       2016-01-08     30590667          RSFR                   0   
695359       2016-01-05     38367349          RSFR                   0   
695360       2016-01-06     28343751          RSFR                   0   
695361       2016-01-06     28276045          RSFR                   0   
695362       2016-01-07     28231813          RSFR                   0   
695364       2016-01-05     29231869          RSFR              186500   
695365       2016-01-08     99508739          RSFR                   0   
695366       2016-01-08     32802312          RSFR                   0   
695367       2016-01-11     31039686          RCON                   0   
695371       2016-01-14     24678457          RSFR                   0   
695375       2016-01-12     25785995          RCON              260000   
695379       2016-01-05     32675204          RSFR                   0   
695380       2016-01-05     32675204          RSFR                   0   
695386       2016-01-06     24753709          RMSC              182500   
695391       2016-01-05     80343135          RSFR                   0   
695393       2016-01-04     39455719          RSFR                   0   
695396       2016-01-02     23860426          RSFR                   0   
695400       2016-01-06     31724849          RSFR                   0   
695401       2016-01-05     31782489          RSFR                   0   
695404       2016-01-08     39277369          RCON                   0   
695414       2016-01-14     29279706          RMOB                8500   
695415       2016-01-06     39233214          RCON                   0   
695416       2016-01-04     24133173          RSFR                   0   
695417       2016-01-08    119423152          RSFR              410000   
695419       2016-01-06    156790379          RSFR                   0   
695420       2016-01-06     28370240          RSFR                   0   
695421       2016-01-18     29444872          RSFR                   0   
695422       2016-01-08    119686348          RCON                   0   
695423       2016-01-11    114723813          RSFR                   0   
695424       2016-01-08     27353005          RCON                   0   
695425       2016-01-11     27736737          RMOB                   0   

        loan_amount                     lender  sqft  year_built  trans_yr  
695169            0                        NaN  1658        1998      2016  
695252            0                        NaN   824        1963      2016  
695285            0                        NaN  1316        1941      2016  
695314            0                        NaN   936        1983      2016  
695320            0                        NaN  1510        1973      2016  
695324            0                        NaN     0           0      2016  
695326            0                        NaN   594        1985      2016  
695328            0                        NaN  1314        1988      2016  
695335            0                        NaN  2797        1979      2016  
695336            1      HUD-HOUSING/URBAN DEV  1288        1925      2016  
695342       350000             PROVIDENT FNDG  2714        1998      2016  
695345      2750000            FIRST CHOICE BK     0           0      2016  
695346       175000         BANK OF AMERICA/IL   836        1985      2016  
695349       219500       PARAMOUNT EQUITY MTG  2569        2000      2016  
695350            0                        NaN  1532        1957      2016  
695351       172000             INTERFIRST MTG  1390        1956      2016  
695352        35000            TCF NAT'L BK/AZ  3887        2004      2016  
695353       400000             PROVIDENT FNDG  2462           0      2016  
695355            0                        NaN  1726        1910      2016  
695357       358250                QUICKEN LNS  3113        1987      2016  
695359       374853                 FREMONT BK  1881        1999      2016  
695360       665000                      US BK  2285        1971      2016  
695361       359100           NETWORK CAP FNDG  3620        2005      2016  
695362        27600       WELLS FARGO BK NW NA  2286        1996      2016  
695364       183121              THE MTG HOUSE  1775        1981      2016  
695365       262500  * OTHER INSTITUTIONAL LEN  2578        2002      2016  
695366       317175        RESIDENTIAL BANCORP   878        1957      2016  
695367       100000       WELLS FARGO BK NW NA  1127        1983      2016  
695371            0                        NaN  2337        1970      2016  
695375       255290             SAN DIEGO FNDG  1111        1984      2016  
695379            0                        NaN  2447        1973      2016  
695380            0                        NaN  2447        1973      2016  
695386            0                        NaN     0           0      2016  
695391            0                        NaN  1952        1958      2016  
695393       183200            GUARANTEED RATE  1678        1978      2016  
695396       144620             CARDINAL FIN'L  1305        1955      2016  
695400      1000000   CITY NAT'L BK/CHARLESTON  1990        2015      2016  
695401            0                        NaN  2759        1938      2016  
695404       328500     FINANCE OF AMERICA MTG  1012        1976      2016  
695414            0                        NaN   732        1970      2016  
695415       198000         PRIVATE INDIVIDUAL  1051        1980      2016  
695416        75000            TCF NAT'L BK/AZ  1050        1955      2016  
695417       402573       FIRST PRIORITY FIN'L  2216        2006      2016  
695419       736000                     WFB NA  3729        2014      2016  
695420            0                        NaN  2595        1958      2016  
695421            0                        NaN  1756        1958      2016  
695422       710400         JP MORGAN CHASE BK  2010        2007      2016  
695423            0                        NaN  1886        2007      2016  
695424       239920                     WFB NA  2027        1991      2016  
695425            0                        NaN  1440        1972      2016 


Update:

pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.13.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 16.7.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.22.0
pytest: 3.0.5
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 27.2.0
Cython: 0.25.2
numpy: 1.14.0
scipy: 1.0.0
pyarrow: None
xarray: None
IPython: 5.1.0
sphinx: 1.5.1
patsy: 0.5.0
dateutil: 2.6.1
pytz: 2017.3
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.0
tables: 3.3.0
numexpr: 2.6.1
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.0.0
openpyxl: 2.4.1
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlwt: 1.2.0
xlsxwriter: 0.9.6
lxml: 3.7.2
bs4: 4.5.3
html5lib: None
sqlalchemy: 1.2.1
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.9.4
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
```

Data:

```
data_16.dtypes

id                             int64
property_address              object
buyer                         object
seller                        object
transaction_date      datetime64[ns]
property_id                    int64
property_type                 object
transaction_amount             int64
loan_amount                    int64
lender                        object
sqft                           int64
year_built                     int64
trans_yr                       int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I test it and for me it working nice, what are your `dtype`s? Also what is your pandas version? Last is `0.22.0`.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for getting back to me on this.  I've added an update above with the pandas version and the dtypes.  My pandas is 0.22.0 and the dtype for property_type is object.  Are you getting non-zero values when you sum the propType_dummies?

Comment: For me it working nice. Are data confidental?

Comment: @jezrael Yeah, I don't really want to share all the data.  Plus it's like 2 million records.  I checked the fill rate and property_type is there for every record.  So I can't see how these values could wind up being 0.0.  I did the same thing for the year_built field and it comes out non-zero.  I'm on a mac, would that matter at all?

Comment: try filter first 1k data, maybe some big data problem. Really hard to find solution :(

Comment: @jezrael I sampled 0.1% of the data, and tested the code.  It gave me non-zero values when I ran describe.  But the means are coming out really small.  Also I just noticed that when I ran data_16.nunique() it returns a value of 12 for property_type but there's only 10 columns being returned when I run get_dummies.

Comment: Hmmm, solution is add RAM :( Or processes data in some server with more RAM. :(

Comment: @jezrael  Thanks, yeah I just noticed too that with the original dataframe all 12 values show up in get_dummies.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @jezrael  I just converted the get_dummies to float64 and that seems to have solved the problem.